# BIML troubleshoot File Move

Tags: biml

I am trying to write a simple File move loop, but i know I am missing a couple things.
1. probably missing the variable that goes through all the files, that are text, and move only the text files, hence i need a variable, but not sure where i would put it in the code below.
2. The error message I am getting is "Required Property 'Source' was not supplied for 'MoveFilesPackage.LoopFilesMove.MoveToDestination'... but i thought i got it? i checked my spelling and capitalization... but still not showing up :(
let me know if i am missing anything else for this to run right and move datafiles from one directory to another :(
Biml Code below:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Connections>
  <FileConnection Name="File_Source" FilePath="\\pc1\Documents\HMS\" RelativePath ="true"/>
  <FileConnection Name="File_Destination" FilePath="\\pc1\Documents\HMS\Archive_Test\" RelativePath ="true"/>
</Connections>
<Packages>
    <Package Name="MoveFilesPackage" ConstraintMode="Linear">
        <Variables>
            <Variable Name="FileSource" Namespace="user" DataType="String"></Variable>
            <Variable Name="FileDestination" Namespace="user" DataType="String"></Variable>
        </Variables>
        <Tasks>
            <ForEachFileLoop Name="LoopFilesMove" Folder="User::FileSource" ConstraintMode="Linear" FileSpecification="*.txt">
                <Tasks>
                    <FileSystem Name="MoveToDestination" Operation="MoveFile">
                        <Expressions>
                            <Expression PropertyName="Source" ExternalProperty="User::FileSource"></Expression>
                            <Expression PropertyName="Destination" ExternalProperty="User::FileDestination"></Expression>
                        </Expressions>
                    </FileSystem>
                </Tasks>
            </ForEachFileLoop>
        </Tasks>
    </Package>
</Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: The folder on your foreachfileloop looks incorrect. It will be getting the string value of `User::FileSource` instead of \\pc1\documents...  take a look at my post on the [FileSystemTask](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2014/02/biml-file-system-task.html) While I don't explicitly use the `MoveFile` Operation, it should become apparent

Comment: OK found 1 fix, however getting a different error message, error message saying "System.collections.DictionaryEntry Exception Type: ExpressionSyntaxException C:\... blah blah SSIS path 19 34" code I added below after the foreachfileloop and tasks:   <FileSystem Name="MoveToDestination" Operation="MoveFile">
                        <FileInput ConnectionName="File_Source"/>
                        <FileOutput ConnectionName="File_Destination"/>

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the Varigence Biml forums where it was cross-posted:
https://varigence.com/Forums?threadID=9737

Here is the minimal code sample that was provided there:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Packages>
    <Package Name="MoveFilesPackage" ConstraintMode="Linear">
        <Variables>
            <Variable Name="SourceFilePath" DataType="String">c:\temp</Variable>
        </Variables>
        <Tasks>
            <ForEachFileLoop Name="LoopFilesMove" Folder="\\pc1\Documents\HMS\" ConstraintMode="Linear" FileSpecification="*.txt" RetrieveFileNameFormat="FullyQualified">
                <VariableMappings>
                    <VariableMapping Name="0" VariableName="User.SourceFilePath" />
                </VariableMappings>
                <Tasks>
                    <FileSystem Name="MoveToDestination" Operation="MoveFile">
                        <VariableInput VariableName="User.SourceFilePath" />
                        <ExternalFileOutput ExternalFilePath="\\pc1\Documents\HMS\Archive_Test\" />
                    </FileSystem>
                </Tasks>
            </ForEachFileLoop>
        </Tasks>
    </Package>
</Packages>
</Biml>
```